# use of undeclared identifier 'LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED' After #import "MagicalPanda/MagicalRecord.h' file not found.

Tags: ios, cocoapods, magicalrecord

I downloaded an App demo to study,after solving some problems I found out,I got stuck again and this time I can't deal with it.

Before this error I met another.
     #import "MagicalPanda/MagicalRecord.h' file not found. 
And I solve it according to https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Installing-MagicalRecord.md ,I use CocoaPods and add pod 'MagicalRecord/CocoaLumberjack' to my Podfile, then I had the following error.

```
MRLogWarn(@"Property '%@' not found in %lx properties for %@", propertyName, (unsigned long)[propDict count], NSStringFromClass(self));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY8gY.png)
Just like this.

What can I do now.

Comment: Have you also included "CocoaLumberjack.h"?

Comment: No,the demo doesn't include.Am I supposed?

Comment: I believe that if you use the `MagicalRecord/CocoaLumbercjack` you need to include it

Comment: Thanks.I know how CocoaLumberjack works now,the demo didn't  use it so I delete.But the problem come back to initial error,'MagicalPanda/MagicalRecord.h' file not found.So sad.

Comment: Instead include "MagicalRecord/CocoaLumbercjack.h" if use framework in podfile you must make @import "MagicalRecord"

Comment: On LOG_ASYNC_ENABLE it's because u are using lumberjack > 2.4

Comment: @teixeiras thanks. I deleted it and it works.